# Using odds ratios to find probabilities/proportions of a population

Tags: odds-ratio

I have the following odds ratios for a person in a given age group having a certain condition:

Ages 50 and above: $OR =1$

Ages 40-49: $OR = 1.67$

Ages 30-39: $OR = 2.43$

Ages 20-29: $OR = 3.36$

If I also know that $43.5\%$ of people aged 20-50 have this condition, then how do I determine what proportion in each age group have the condition?

Comment: It looks to me the figures you gave are just "odds" instead of "odds ratio".

Comment: They're odds ratios estimated from a logistic regression model.

Comment: So there should be a baseline group, right? You should point it out or give more information. Odds ratio should refer to TWO groups, it's hard for me to understand something like "the OR of Ages 40-49 is 1.67".

Comment: The baseline group is the one with an OR of 1.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.

Comment: By the way, it's also obvious which group is the baseline by the definition of an odds ratio together with there being only one group with OR one and the reasonable assumption that all groups are listed.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ be the proportions having the condition in age group "50 or above", "40-49", "30-39", and "20-29" respectively. By condition, you can set up the following system:
\begin{align}
& \frac{p_2}{1 - p_2}  = 1.67\frac{p_1}{1 - p_1} \\
& \frac{p_3}{1 - p_3}  = 2.43\frac{p_1}{1 - p_1} \\
& \frac{p_4}{1 - p_4}  = 3.36\frac{p_1}{1 - p_1} \\
&  p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 = 0.435
\end{align}
Solve this system for $p_1, \ldots, p_4$ to get the result.

Comment: I do follow, but shouldn't the last line be a weighted average of the $p_i$'s $= .435$? (weighted by the size of the age groups)

Comment: No, just think the whole population has $N$ individuals, then there would be $N_1 = N \times (p_1 + \cdots + p_4)$ people having the condition, hence the proportion of having condition is given by $N_1/N = p_1 + \cdots + p_4$.